# How to fix type error in F# function arguments

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I have a program that is trying to take in a list of ints and return a int list that has all the odd numbers from it, i'm new to functional programming and am trying to learn it with F#.  When I try and call the `removeEvens` in `main` it gives me this error

```
Error   FS0001  This expression was expected to have type
    'int list -> 'a'    
but here has type
    ''b list'
```

and here is my code

```fs
open System

let rec removeEvens arr count ret =
    if count < 0 then
        ret
    else
        if count % 2 = 0 then
            removeEvens arr (count + 1) ret
        else
            removeEvens arr (count + 1) (arr[count] :: ret)

let rec printResults arr count =
    if count > 0 then
        printfn "%d" (arr[count])
        printResults arr (count + 1)


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printResults (removeEvens [0 .. 100] 0 []) 0
    0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntactically, the only problem here is that the index operator is missing a `.` character. So you want `arr.[count]` instead of `arr[count]` (which the F# compiler thinks is the application of a function called `arr` to a singleton list, hence the compiler error). In order to use indexing, you'll also need to explicitly annotate your `arr` value as a list, like this: `(arr : List<_>)`.

Semantically, you should be aware that indexing into lists in this way is inefficient, but that's a separate issue. I suggest instead that a more elegant way to remove even numbers from a list is to consider only the head element of the list inside your recursive function.